# Name object by string variable

Tags: java, date

The idea is to get the current year that the system is running in, then name the study record after the year and therefore refer to it as the current year.

Basically just get the string variable and then use it as the name of an object. I have seen similar but not accurate as I want it and lack the explanation I am looking for.

```
Date now = new Date();c // get the current date    
String CurrentYearRecord = Integer.toString(now.getYear()); // set a string variable that I will use to name my object
StudyRecord CurrentYearRecord = new StudyRecord(); // name my object the string year that I got from the previous line.
```

Comment: You cant name variables dynamically. Maybe you will be interested in `Map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, manipulating variable names at runtime is not possible in Java language.
This kind of feature is only possible in dynamic languages, like Python or Javascript.

In plain java, you can use a Map to achieve what you need:

```
Map<String, StudyRecord> records;
// init your map and fill it when relevant

StudyRecord currentYearRecord = records.get(Integer.toString(now.getYear()))
```

If you really need this feature, have a look at [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/), which is a dynamic language running on the JVM with a close syntax to Java.

Comment: So I am assuming to get the currentYearRecord I can use 2014.get(index)? I am getting where you are going, just not sure how this changes the way you manipulate the data structure?

Comment: No unfortunately, you can't "create" a variable name at runtime. Use an hashmap is a trick to dynamise variable usage.

Comment: Thank you. Got it sorted with your Map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HashMap` to store the name you want as key and use the value in the value of `HashMap`. But that's not exactly naming a variable in runtime.